# Can't send files using bluetooth from Phone to Windows 8.1 PC

Tags: 8.1, bluetooth, windows-8

I tried connecting with my Dell Windows 8.1 PC using Bluetooth to sent a file from Phone. I am getting this error

[image]

But I can transfer files from PC to Phone. Is this any driver problem of my PC or authentication problem of Phone? How could I transfer files from Phone to PC using Bluetooth?

Comment: if you are trying to send music or videos it wont work. because windows phone blocks sharing of these media files due to copyright. it doesn't matter whether they are recorded from your phone or downloaded. however i have been successful in transferring photos. Sometimes your computer or phone model might not support certain types of Bluetooth profiles. for eg in your case the phone might not support sending but it might support receiving or the computer might not support sending to your specific model of phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to transfer files from your Windows Phone 8 to your PC is by simply connecting it through USB. You then should see it as a USB device and access photos, music etc.

You can also synchronise your photos through OneDrive and then download them on your Windows 8.1 machine.

If you need to use Bluetooth transfer, try using the "fsquirt" tool.
http://plugable.com/2013/11/11/easy-way-to-use-bluetooth-to-exchange-files-with-your-phone-in-windows-fsquirt-guide

Comment: I am only asking for the Bluetooth file transfer!

Comment: Have you checked the link I posted?

Comment: This worked for me! I paired the devices, then using fsquirt.exe tool I selected 'Receive files' and then shared the file from Phone to PC. Thanks! I think the reason is, the devices became connected only after I authenticated the PC to receive files. Is that right?

Comment: Well afaik Windows does not know how to handle incoming files on its own, that's why you need the fsquirt tool.

Comment: I recommend moving the last line of your answer to the top. The earlier lines are not relevant to this question. USB might be easiest for you, but not the easiest for everyone in every situation. With onedrive, one opens a huge can of privacy-worms.

Answer (score 11):

I am also facing this problem. But solution is simple....
 Just right click the Bluetooth icon on the task bar and select Receive a File... Then send files through Phone... Its Working.....[image]

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: yup agree with Nagendra, this is the best and easiest way to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you are using Windows 8/8.1, follow these steps please:

1. Go to **PC settings** >> **PC and devices** >> **Bluetooth**.
2. Turn on bluetooth both on PC and your phone.
3. Phone is discoverable for only a limited amount of time(approx. 2 minutes), when you find your phone select it and tap **Pair**.
4. Compare the passcodes and press **Add** to add that phone to your PC's bluetooth devices.
5. To send a file from phone to PC, open the file tap **share** >> **bluetooth** and select the destination PC.
6. To send a file to your phone, right click on that file to open **context menu** >> **Send to** >> **Bluetooth** and select the phone where you want to transfer the file.

Now, if the phone is removed from your bluetooth devices list on PC, you will get error messages. Try reconnecting phone to your PC with steps 1 to 4. Thats it!

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is just about the pairing only. My devices are already paired. I tried pairing again by removing the devices, but getting the same error again!

Answer (score 0):

If your device is paired with your laptop via Bluetooth, then you should be able to transfer data from your phone to your laptop.

Some instructions:

1. Open My Computer, where you can access your drives.
2. There will be folder named Bluetooth (or the name of your paired device).
3. Open that folder.
4. Copy the data or send data to that folder.

It works when I do it.

I got the same problem as you and you can fix it by opening your Bluetooth folder located under My Computer.

Comment: Are you talking about the Windows Phone? See the answer which was accepted. I think Windows Phone doesn't show up as a Bluetooth device in 'My Computer'.

Comment: There's a bug in Windows 8.1 - The bluetooth device shows up a few times, then disappears forever. The only solution is to reinstall Windows (as per MS), otherwise, you have to send files one at a time. :(
This is probably why the WinPhone is being discontinued.